# Using GItHub with Visual Studio Projects (.csproj) including references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, github, csproj

Me and my team just started using GitHub for our development.
Our project is written within Visual Studio (C#).

In our project files we have external references of .dll files that are saved in specific folder for each user for example (c:\users\$user\dlls\data.dll).

When one user is commiting it's changes - it's also including the .csproj files who contain the links for those .dlls but when another using is pulling from the tree the .csproj contains links from the other user's .dll file and he have to change manually the references in order for it to work.

We tried solving it by putting the .csproj files into .gtignore - though that back fired once our project development expended and each branch has different files.

During the writing of this post I thought of another solution - removing the .csproj from the .gtignore and moving all the external .dlls into folder with an agreed file path such as (c:\dlls) and that might solve our problem.

My question is this:

1. Is there another solution for our issue?
2. I haven't tested my suggested my solution I will give it a try next version - What do you think of it? Is that the way to go?

Thanks ahead for your replies,
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you "sharing" those external DLLs in a folder in your project? What I do is add a folder named "External" in my solution which contains these DLLs (and PDBs and XMLs etc) and make sure it is also checked in. That way whenever someone adds a DLL, all other developers simply need to get the latest files from Git and it is on their machines.

Of course, only do this for DLLs that aren't available from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a dependency manager such as NuGet or an alternative one.